# How does Heroku handle Django dependencies?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm starting to work on my first-ever Django/Heroku project – I'm working on a friend's web app that's already partially coded. It's built in Django 1.6. There's no `virtualenv`, and when I clone it and try to run it in Django 1.8 it crashes and burns. The app itself is currently online and functional, and when I run the app locally in Django 1.6, no issues. How is Heroku handling dependencies like this? Does it install dependencies on its server by reading the `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku installs whatever versions of python packages you specify in your `requirements.txt` file. For example, if it contains:

```
requests
Django
```

it will install the latest version available of those packages, as no version is specified. If, on the contrary, you want/need Heroku to install version X.Y of a package, you need to specify so in the requirements file, like:

```
requests==2.6.2
Django==1.8
```

That will make heroku install `requests` and `Django` at versions 2.6.2 and 1.8, respectively.

UPDATE: As an extra note, be aware that this is nothing specific to Heroku. Heroku simply runs `pip install -r requirements.txt` and the result is the same as if you run it locally.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku only uses the libraries in your requirements.txt file. Whatever version of Django is specified there is what it will install.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies can be installed through the [pip requirements.txt file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip). You may also specify in your [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) a script to run when your web instance is started. I personally have a run script referred from the Procfile that runs my Pyramid (a web framework similar to DJango) setup.py file for deployment, which could alternatively install dependencies.

Comment: Thanks I definitely appreciate the info. But my question is really, how does Heroku know which version of Django to run after I've deployed the app? I know how to install dependencies on my machine, but does Heroku install dependencies on the server they use to run the app?

Answer (score 0):

There are three configuration files that go into your Heroku deploy:

1. runtime.txt: Here you can specify your python runtime. It's optional, I believe default is 2.7.9.
2. requirements.txt: this file contains the python dependencies that should be installed into your python environment. During the deploy Heroku will run:

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

   which will install all dependencies contained in the file. If you've got pip installed in your local environment(it comes bundled with python 3.4, you may need to install it separately for other runtimes), you should be able to generate the contents of this file for your local environment by running:

   ```
   pip freeze
   ```
3. Procfile: Here you should define the commands that your Heroku dynos will run. Typically, the command for running your Django project.

Comment: Thanks I definitely appreciate the info. But my question is really, how does Heroku know which version of Django to run after I've deployed the app? I know how to install dependencies on my machine, but does Heroku install dependencies on the server they use to run the app?

Comment: Dependencies are installed as specified on your requirements file. Pip will download the latest stable version unless the requirements file dictates otherwise. You can include the django version in the requirements like so: Django==1.6 (if you want version 1.6)